# Accordion Does Not Close on the mouse click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, accordionpane

I have made the accordion and its working fine but when it is slide down and when we click on it to slide upwards it doesn't go upward towards the closing position. Below is my code kindly tell how to proceed?

```
(function($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: [**Googled code snippet**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/) and that tutorial has [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/VPfJ5/3/). As the OP states, it does not scroll back up again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/DDUQ5/1/

```
(function($) {

 var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

 $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $target =  $this.parent().next();
  allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
  if($target.is(':hidden')){
     allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
     $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
  }

 return false;
 });

})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: **+1** Excellent answer, but it's best if they all have 'slow' or if that's just not used. In other words, have all the animations for the same time. That way, while one tab is closing, another is opening at the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the issue you are sliding up the hidden elements

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
```

instead try this one:

```
(function($) {
   var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
   $('.accordion > dt > a').toggle(function() {
      allPanels.slideUp();
      $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
      return false;
   },function() {
      $(this).parent().next().slideUp();
      return false;
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It doesn't change behavior of his code. You are only selecting the same elements twice.

Comment: just updated the answer. use **toggle** instead **click** in this scenario. Try and see if this helps.